# Encode parameter before executing the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swashbuckle, swagger-codegen, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

We are using `.NET Core 3.1` and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.6.3`.

Some of our controller actions require `User-Identity` HTTP header to be sent in the request. The value of this `User-Identity` HTTP header is base64-encoded JSON object. Example:

JSON object

```json
{
  "email": "test@test.com"
}
```

is encoded in base64 as:

`ewogICJFbWFpbCI6ICJ0ZXN0QHRlc3QuY29tIgp9`.

We implemented the following filter operation which checks if controller action has `[RequireUserIdentityFilterAttribute]` attribute and adds a parameter accordingly.

```cs
public class RequireUserIdentityOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
  public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
  {
    // check if controller action has RequireUserIdentityFilterAttribute with reflection
    var hasRequireUserIdentityFilterAttribute = context.MethodInfo
      .GetCustomAttributes(true)
      .OfType<RequireUserIdentityFilterAttribute>()
      .Any();

    if (hasRequireUserIdentityFilterAttribute)
    {
      operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
      {
        Description = "Base-64 encoded user email object. Example: { \"Email\": \"test@test.com\" } => ewogICJFbWFpbCI6ICJ0ZXN0QHRlc3QuY29tIgp9",
        Name = "User-Identity",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Schema = new OpenApiSchema
        {
          Type = "string",
          Example = new OpenApiString("ewogICJFbWFpbCI6ICJ0ZXN0QHRlc3QuY29tIgp9")
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This is how it looks like in SwaggerUI:

[image]

It works fine as-is. `User-Identity` header is sent to the server.

However, it is not very user-friendly because user has to input a string which must be base64-encoded. Is it possible that we simplify the input so that the user will only have to input user email (ex. `test@test.com`) and C# will handle the base64 encoding before the request is sent to the server?

Comment: If you use a MIME attachment than you do not needed to encode.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true  the MIME attachment is in the body of the message and starts with two dashes on a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwaggerUI uses JavaScript to send the requests to the server. You could inject a script that intercepts the request and changes the header before transmitting it to the server, e.g.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    // ...
    var adjustHeaders = @"(request) => {
        let header = request.headers["User-Identity"];
        if (header && header.length > 0) {
          // header is a JSON object
          if (header[0] == "{") header = 
            btoa(header);
          // header is an email address
          else if (header.indexOf("@") >= 0) 
            header = btoa(JSON.stringify({ email: header }));
          // Otherwise assume that it is already encoded
          request.headers["User-Identity"] = header;
        }
        return request;
    }";
    c.UseRequestInterceptor(adjustHeaders);
});
```

Above script is a pseudo-Javascript that can give you a starting point. Please test it in the browser whether it works in your situation and for the browsers your SwaggerUI targets.

Comment: This seems like the right approach, thank you. One small note: `UseRequestInterceptor` is not available in `5.6.3`, I had to update the package to `6.4.0`.